# Unable to create straight connectors in jsplumb

Tags: jsplumb

I'm using version 2.15 of jsplumb in an Angular project and am trying to create straight connections between the elements. The code below initiates the instance

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
      Container: '.diagram'
    });
    // can I add other defaults here?
  }
```

I create the connection like this

```
this.jsPlumbInstance.connect({
            source,
            target,
            anchors: ['Bottom', 'Top'],
            detachable: false,
            endpoint: 'Dot'
          });
```

which results in curvy lines between anchors. I tried to add a 'connector' property above setting it to 'straight' or ['straight'], but that leads to the 'unknown connector type 'straight' error. The docs [here](https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/toolkit/current/articles/connectors.html) do not specify the syntax and the link to it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

i had to set the connector on the instance

```
this.jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
          Container: '.diagram',
          Connector: 'Straight',
          Endpoints: [
            ['Dot', { radius: 3 }],
            ['Dot', { radius: 3 }]
          ],
          ConnectionsDetachable: true,
          Anchors: ['Bottom', 'Top']
        });
```

anyone knows how to make all elements draggable in the community edition?